# avoiding prefixes with java-ws and apache cfx

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf

I'm using jax-ws with apache cxf every things seems ok , except the prefix in soap envelope
It looks like this now

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
      <ns2:CreateCustomer xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org">
          <ns2:myVar>
          </ns2:myVar>
      <ns2:CreateCustomer xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org">
```

I'm trying to avoid the prefixes but keep the xmlns to look like this ...

```
      <CreateCustomer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <myVar>
```

Comment: What end of the service are you developing? The web service client or the web service?

Comment: First of all I'm new to web services in J2ee and I was using Web service client ..  then I solved it by using the wsimport tool to create all mapping classes from the wsdl ..  the main problem was with @SOAPBinding thing ..